# how to string compare two columns in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df that looks like this:

```
        a      b
  0     Jon     Jon
  1     Jon     John
  2     Jon     Johnny
```

And I'd like to compare these two strings to and make a new column like such:

```
  df['compare'] = df2['a'] = df2['b']


        a      b          compare
  0     Jon     Jon         True
  1     Jon     John        False
  2     Jon     Johnny      False
```

I'd also like to be able to pass columns a and b through this levenshtein function:

```
def levenshtein_distance(a, b):
    """Return the Levenshtein edit distance between two strings *a* and *b*."""
    if a == b:
        return 0
    if len(a) < len(b):
        a, b = b, a
    if not a:
        return len(b)
    previous_row = range(len(b) + 1)
    for i, column1 in enumerate(a):
        current_row = [i + 1]
        for j, column2 in enumerate(b):
            insertions = previous_row[j + 1] + 1
            deletions = current_row[j] + 1
            substitutions = previous_row[j] + (column1 != column2)
            current_row.append(min(insertions, deletions, substitutions))
        previous_row = current_row
    return previous_row[-1]
```

and add a column like such:

```
  df['compare'] = levenshtein_distance(df2['a'], df2['b'])      

        a      b          compare
   0    Jon     Jon         100
   1    Jon     John        .95
   2    Jon     Johnny      .87
```

However I am getting this error when I try:

```
  ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How can I format my data/dataframe to allow it to compare the two columns and add taht comparison as a third column?

Comment: Have you looked at apply? That's how i normally apply functions like these

Comment: I'm a newb so still learning a lot.  I'm just not sure why I can pass two strings by themselves to levenshtein, but not loop through the rows and do it?

Comment: @user3486773 when you call `levenshtein_distance(df2['a'], df2['b'])`, the arguments you pass are now Series, not strings. Thus a comparison like `a==b` compares the entire Series. In `pandas` this performs an element-wise comparison, but you use that in an `if` statement. So what single truth value characterizes [True, False, True, True, False, …]? Your function is implemented to work on two individual strings, which is appropriate for levenshtein_distance. However you need to call it with the proper inputs, two strings, not Series, since that's what your function expects.

Comment: @user3486773 i modified my answer on this one to calculate the percentage, can i use it to answer your other question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59076746/comparing-two-simple-strings-in-pandas-using-levenshtein  or do you want me to post it here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do:

```
df['compare'] = [levenshtein_distance(a, b) for a, b in zip(df2['a'], df2['b'])]
```

Or, if you want equality comparison:

```
df['compare'] = (df['a'] == df['b'])
```

Comment: Arent the elements of a an b iterables (strings)?

Comment: yes, but if it's meant to be applied to pd.Series, you can't just throw strings at it

Comment: @mcsoini I dont understand what you mean, the function Levenshtein is made for strings, what do you mean by pd.Series?

Comment: OP `df['compare'] = levenshtein_distance(df2['a'], df2['b'])` means `a` and `b` are pandas series

Comment: IMHO, the OP whants to compute the levenshtein distance between *parallel* elements of the series i.e. levenshtein_distance('Jon', 'Jon') = 0 ...

Comment: @mcsoini how do I make these into a series on the fly to accomplish the end result?  I'm not quite sure how to account for this in a straight forward manner.

Comment: @Daniel, that is precisely what I want to do but when I run the solution given I get a TypeError: _() takes 1 positional arguement but 3 were given

Comment: This is kinda reinventing the wheel, are you aware that there quite mature modules for this already: `difflib`, `python-Levenshtein`, `fuzzywuzzy`

Comment: @Daniel, i see now, somehow my index looks like it's actually part of column a and not a separate index

Comment: @Erfan, I'm on a locked down server python that can't install new libs.

Answer (score 1):

I think you compares are wrong, change:

change:

```
if a == b

and not a
```

to

```
if a[0] == b[0]

and 

not a[0]
```

and you'll see that your function works, it just needs to iterate through the df's you pass. And your equal will return if you return a list

Here's a working version:

```
def levenshtein_distance(a, b):
  """Return the Levenshtein edit distance between two strings *a* and *b*."""
  y = len(a)
  thelist = []
  for x in range(0, y):
    c = a[x]
    d = b[x] 
    if c == d:
        thelist.append(0)
        continue
    if len(c) < len(d):
        c, d = d, c
    if not c:
        thelist.append(len(d))
        continue
    previous_row = range(len(d) + 1)
    for i, column1 in enumerate(c):
        current_row = [i + 1]
        for j, column2 in enumerate(d):
            insertions = previous_row[j + 1] + 1
            deletions = current_row[j] + 1
            substitutions = previous_row[j] + (column1 != column2)
            current_row.append(min(insertions, deletions, substitutions))
        previous_row = current_row
    thelist.append(previous_row[-1])
  return thelist
```

```
df['compare'] =  levenshtein_distance(df.a, df.b)                                                                                                                

df                                                                                                                                                               

#     a       b  compare
#0  Jon     Jon        0
#1  Jon    John        1
#2  Jon  Johnny        3
```

It just doesn't calculate the percentages, it just uses your code, which according to [Levenshtein Calc](https://planetcalc.com/1721/) is the right answers